# Is it possible to hide the exponent using siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

E.g. if all numbers in a table have the same fixed exponent or if I decide to print numbers like 0.5 in percent as 50%. If not is there another way/package to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\sisetup{fixed-exponent=-2, scientific-notation=false}
current output: \num{0.54111} or

\sisetup{fixed-exponent=-2, scientific-notation=fixed}
current output: \num{0.54111}

\sisetup{fixed-exponent=-2, scientific-notation=false}
wanted output:  \num{54.111}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just write the exponent in the column head…

Comment: Thats what I want, but how do I hide it in the other rows. To clarify, I have hundreds of numbers in multiple tables all in the format 0.xxxxx and I would like to avoid to move the decimal point by hand for all of them.

Comment: I mean, not the first cell with numbers, but a real column head, summarising what the column numbers are all about.

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I want to do but how can get siunitx to not print the exponent in all the cells with the numbers. Maybe its just too late ...

Comment: `siunitx` manual, p. 55, '`table-omit-exponent`' option, _etc._

Comment: That does exactly what I wanted. Must have overlooked it in the manual. Thank you both. Is there also a way to get this behavior outside of a table?

Comment: @fhllw Deliberately not: it would be misleading to simply drop the exponent generally, but not in a table column.

Comment: I understand that but it would be nice to have an easy way to switch between the representations of percentages (ratio <> number). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joseph Wright pointed out in his comment the behavior I was looking for can be achieved in tables using the `table-omit-exponent` option [(manaul p. 55)](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en). A way to achieve this outside of table environments exists "deliberately not".

An example using the tabu package defining a new column type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{S[
  fixed-exponent=-2,
  table-omit-exponent,
  round-mode=places,
  round-precision={#1}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{XXP{2}}
           & ratio & {percent} \\
  a number & 0.419242894984 & 0.419242894984 \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]