# Hide the factor before the exponent in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

This question is the opposite of [Is it possible to hide the exponent using siunitx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323549/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-exponent-using-siunitx).

I have input data like the following (from a auto-generated CSV file so changing the input should be avoided):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[round-mode=figures, round-precision=1, exponent-mode=scientific, table-format=1e1]}
  10\\
  100\\
  1000\\
  10000\\
  100000\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

It gives the following output:

[image: output]

Now I'd like to suppress the factor preceding the exponent (i.e. the `1\times` part which will always be `1\times` in this case). How would I go about it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? the `1\times` part?

Comment: @daleif Yes, exactly. Isn't it called factor? Is there another word?

Comment: So, basically you want to extract the order of magnitude of your values, right? Because from a scientific point of view, the factor (even when it is 1) is required for the value to make sense.

Comment: @MarkusG. Exactly, although in this case numbers are always powers of 10 and I need horizontal space in my table. Hence, the 1 is not required to make sense ;)

Comment: In "scientific" notation, the part before `\times` is called the *mantissa*.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, should have thought of that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Under the new `siunitx`, the key is `print-zero-exponent=true, print-unity-mantissa=false`.  EDITED to add more range to the data.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[round-mode=figures, round-precision=1, 
  exponent-mode=scientific, table-format=1e1, print-zero-exponent=true, 
  print-unity-mantissa=false]}
  .01\\
  .1\\
  1\\
  10\\
  100\\
  1000\\
  10000\\
  100000\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The new feature is described on p.28 of the current (2021-07-06) manual

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks, haven't found that from skimming the docs. I'll try it as soon as I'm back at my computer and then accept.

Comment: @TeXnician There have been recent significant changes.  Make sure you have the latest package version.

Comment: @TeXnician both can be found on p.28 of the current manual.

Comment: Much appreciated, it works great. And somehow I did not see this mantissa example in the manual.